# 3d Maya object mesh problems when used in Unity

Tags: unity, maya

Asking for help to solve a problem 3d Maya objects imported in Unity to make an ios app. Maya object change when imported on Unity mesh attributes disappears and mesh structure comes evident. Has anyone some suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unity converts models to [.fbx format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) when importing them.  As such, mesh attributes aren't retained because the .fbx format doesn't store them.  You can add some things Unity-side to reassign and use attributes—using either scripts or layers depending on your needs.

I'm not sure what you mean by "mesh structure come evident" so I can't offer any insight there.  Can you clarify/reword?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some screenshots to better describe my problem but unfortunately I have not the reputation I need to post it. I'll try to better explain  the situation. In Unity around the meshed Maya object (on black and white instead of colored one)there is the polygonal structure like a cage.

Comment: @ashtag When you select a mesh object in Unity, it will highlight that object--displaying its polygons.  If you select a different object, the first mesh won't be highlighted anymore.  Is what you're seeing something different from that behavior?